# Json encode for PostGre SQL query result using PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql

***I have written PHP code to convert query result to JSON.***

But while using jSON encode, my result only shows `field values`. There is no `field name` in the resulting json file.

### My code:

```
$sql = 'select * from "'.$tablename.'"';
$myarray = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) {
    $myarray[] = $row;
}   
$jsonData = json_encode(array('data' => $myarray));
```

### Result:

```
{"data":[["Bob", "23", "New York"], ["Alice", "20", "Sidney"], ....]}
```

### Expected Result:

```
{"data":[
{"firstName":"Bob", "age":"23", "City":"New York"},
{"firstName":"Alice", "age":"20", "City":"Sidney"},...]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pg_fetch_array()` passing the type as `PGSQL_ASSOC`. Example

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ret,PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
  // your code here
}
```

or just use `pg_fetch_all()`. This will index the resulting array with the column name and there's no need to iterate the result set. Example

```
$myarray = pg_fetch_all($ret);
```

Comment: Plus, instead of using `pg_*` functions, I'd highly recommend to switch to using PDO instead.

Comment: I totally agree @SergeyVidusov, SQL Injection is a common problem to any SQL database. Although, there are some differents when using PDO with PGSQL or with MySQL, example using the `lastInsertId()` require no argument for MySQL.

Comment: i tried both suggestions given above. Both are not giving any results

Comment: I think pg_fetch_all() and pg_fetch_array() functions are nor recognized. I have faced this issue earlier also with these function. Hence I started iterating to access individual rows.

Comment: Once you have installed the postgre extension, all those functions will be available. Using the `pg_fetch_row` indicates that you have the extension and you should have other `pg_*` functions available too. In your code I noticed there's no execution part.

Comment: i am storing the created $jsonData into a .json file.